# The solutions $u,v$ of two differential equations fulfill $u(t)+v(t)=u_0+v_0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $u,v:[0,T_\max)\to\mathbb{R}$ be the solutions of $$\begin{matrix}u'=2u-v-uv&,&u(0)=u_0\in\mathbb{R}\\v'=uv+v-2u&,&v(0)=v_0\in\mathbb{R}\end{matrix}$$
I want to show that it holds $$u(t)+v(t)=u_0+v_0$$ for all $t\in [0,T_\max)$. How can we do that? Which approach yields this result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try adding the equations?

$$u' + v' = 0$$

Hence we can conclude ...

Comment: That's so simple that I feel embarrassed to say I hadn't figured it out on my own.

Comment: Don't worry about it. I should say that I didn't see at first that $u' + v' = 0$. Rather, I started with the solution $u(t) + v(t) = constant$ and thought, "Well, that would be true if $u' + v' = 0$ but that isn't right ... oh wait."